# No provisioning profile with a valid signing identity .No matching provisioning profiles found, xcode, ios

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

This message shows under identity --> Team

> No provisioning profile with a valid signing identity(i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier "com.myname.appname" were found.

Why is this.please help me with this.

I can test with simulator,but cannot test with my iphone.

This is  how the [keychain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goyhy.png) shows

I changed my mac password today

'm using a free account, not a paid one

Comment: have you check provisioning profile? also bundle identifier same as in provisioning profile?also check for App ID added in Xcode

Comment: There is another issue for same is: You might previously created CSR certificate and .p12 file from another machine (or not created at all). That .p12 file you have to installed in your machine OR reset all certificates from your current machine.

Comment: I tried to run sample project and I renamed all files including .plist file, can this also cause for this type of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since release of Xcode 7, developers are allowed to test or run app on any number of devices by logging in with your Apple ID. There is no need of paid Program membership of Apple.

Follow below steps :

- Add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences in Xcode.
- Go to  General tab in Project and choose your team name from the Team pop-up menu.
- Below the Team pop-up menu, click Fix Issue.

[image]

When warning text under the Team menu disappears  , Click the Run button.

Comment: I tried this ,it didn't work previously. but now  it works.thanx

Comment: I just want to add an important note to the accepted answer. Before you follow those mentioned steps don't forget to change bundle identifier to something new if the project was downloaded from internet or other sources.