# Trouble Running App on Device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I'm trying to run my app on a new device through Xcode 7 but everytime I click to run I received this error: "No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities: Features: push and inApp purchase". I don't know what this means. I've never seen a message like this before when running apps on another device with Xcode 7. Does anyone how I can fix this issue so I can run my app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7: "No matching provisioning profiles found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104708/xcode-7-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found)

Comment: this may help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553972/no-provisioning-profile-with-a-valid-signing-identity-no-matching-provisioning

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added your apple developer id to Xcode, I'd suggest doing this now. once you've done this and in the project navigator, if you highlight the project, then on the middle-most pane, go to the `Capabilities Tab` and make sure `In App Purchase` is enabled. If not, enable it. It should pop up asking which developer ID to use, or ask you to add one.

Choose the ID in question, then it'll add the entitlements to the app.

Whats going on here is that the provisioning profile which your app is using, hasn't been enabled in terms of IAP's.

There's more to read about that here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html